# Ubuntu 16.04 - PPTP connecting but no internet

Tags: ubuntu, pptp

I purchased recently a VPS with Ubuntu 16.04 installed on it (OVH). I tried installing a pptp server on it but I have an issue with internet through the VPN.

I am able to connect to the server but I am not getting internet.
Here is my configuration for iptables: (ens3 being the internet interface of the VPS)

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 -o ens3 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --syn -s 192.168.0.0/24 -j TCPMSS --set-mss 1356

dns are set to 
ms-dns 8.8.8.8
ms-dns 8.8.4.4

Would you be able to assit me in fixing the issue?
Thanks a lot

Comment: You *really* should not use PPTP anymore. This is insecure and obsolete. Use OpenVPN, IPSec or Wireguard.

Comment: @sven not all of free hoster support them, and pptp can also use 128bit mppe encryption as its for Private use still fine

Comment: @djdomi: This is exclusively a site for pro administrators. Free hosters and private use are irrelevant here, but PPTP is so broken that it can not  be used for any purpose if you expect real privacy.